# Excel use input from cell in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use text from a cell in a formula this is my formula and i'm wanting to put the sheet name in a cell and have the formula use the cell in place of where the sheet name goes in the formula.

My current formula

```
=VLOOKUP(AL12,'Sheet (2)'!$A:$AA,10,0)
```

Example formula instead of sheet (2) = Text From cell "A1"

```
=VLOOKUP(AL12,'="A1"'!$A:$AA,10,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `Indirect()`:

`=VLOOKUP(AL12,Indirect("'"&$A$1&"'!$A:$AA"),10,0)`